# Correct play? (Hand analysis)

Tags: poker-strategy, hand-history

### 2.50/5 NLH, 7-handed

UTG+1   $687 Raises $12.5

Folds to SB [ME] K♣ 10♥ $557.84 Calls $10

Big Blind $842.19   Calls  $7.50

FLOP J♣10♣7♣

Small Blind [ME]  K♣ 10♥   Bets $20

Big Blind   Folds

UTG+1   Calls $20

TURN 5♥

Small Blind [ME] K♣ 10♥    Bets $50

UTG+1   Raises $110

Small Blind [ME]    All-in(raise) $525.34

UTG+1   Folds   15:02:10

Small Blind [ME]    Wins $293.50

---

I *think* this is generally the correct play, but wanted some thoughts. K♣ gives me very good removal for a flush, and I have some additional equity in the flop with 10s. I am definitely vulnerable to A♣-x and especially A♣J♥ but given that the opponent flat called the flop, I do not think they would have A♣ very often. I overbet jammed rather than a raise because getting re-raised would put me in a terrible position where I have to call off the rest of my stack from behind.

Comment: Raise or fold pre.

Comment: @AndrewChin I think I agree there, probably a good place for a squeeze play- but my question is focused on my action on the flop and turn.

Comment: I'm not sure is betting the flop out of position is the right play. You could end up playing a pot bigger than you want to. Instead, your hand is a pretty nice bluff-catcher to call his potential c-bet

Answer (score 1):

I see in the commments that you would prefer an answer related to the post-flop play. I'd suggest you do not go down that line, it doesn't make sense to pour effort in a scenario that should never happen.

Your hand is a standard fold, I'd be very surprised if any solver does anything else than folding in this situation. Remember, you are 110 BB deep, your range should mostly consist of premium value hands (AJs+) and premium bluffs (78s).

Also, you don't have a range in the SB that ever calls anything from a UTG + 1 raise. You might have an over-calling range with some low pairs (22 - 66) but never a cold calling range. Your option are always fold and 3bet, and here it was a clear fold.